# Cleaning up commas in numbers w/ regular expressions in Python

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have been googling this one fervently, but I can't really narrow it down. I am attempting to interpret a csv file of values, common enough sort of behaviour. But I am being punished by values over a thousand, i.e. in quotations and involving a comma. I have kinda gotten around it by using the csv reader, which creates a list of numbers from the row, but I then have to pick the commas out afterwards.

For purely academic reasons, is there a better way to edit a string with regular expressions?  Going from `08/09/2010,"25,132","2,909",650` to `08/09/2010,25132,2909,650`.

(If you are into Vim, basically I want to put Python on this: 
`:1,$s/"\([0-9]*\),\([0-9]*\)"/\1\2/g` :D )

Comment: Is it that you want to clean up certain fields which contain commas as a part of their value so that they don't need to be quoted? If so, your example is incorrect. You convert `"25,132"` to `25132` but `"2,909"` to `2,909`.

Comment: Ah, whoops! My bad, I want to convert them all later to integers, so I will need a string of pure digits.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to use regular expressions? Removing the commas from a string is trivial with ordinary string methods.

Comment: I thought regular expressions would be a good way to approach it, since I had a specific pattern to go against. I also only wanted to remove the commas from values in quotation marks (and then remove the quotations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is, assuming that commas will only appear in numbers, and that those entries will always be quoted:

```
import re

def remove_commas(mystring):
    return re.sub(r'"(\d+?),(\d+?)"', r'\1\2', mystring)
```

UPDATE:
Adding **cdarke**'s comments below, the following should work for arbitrary-length numbers:

```
import re

def remove_commas_and_quotes(mystring):
    return re.sub(r'","|",|"', ',', re.sub(r'(?:(\d+?),)',r'\1',mystring))
```

Comment: True.  What you'd probably be looking for here is a recursive regular expression that can handle as many digit/comma groupings as you can throw at it.  I have to think about it for a minute.

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I was hoping for! What would you call the notation used here? Basically anything for me to google to read more about :D

Comment: @cdarke - doesn't quite work for me - removes too many commas.  And I don't come close enough to following it to adjust. :)

Comment: To use @cdarke's regex, you need to do another one on top of it.  When I tested his with `'08/09/2010,"25,132","2,909",650,"234,235,452","3,344",234'` I got a result that looks like `'08/09/2010"25132","2909",650"234235452","3344,234'`.

For a completely working version, you should try:
`re.sub(r'","|",|"', ',', re.sub(r'(?:(\d+?),)',r'\1',mystring))`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `csv` module for first-stage parsing, and a regex only for seeing if the result can be transformed to a number.

```
import csv, re
num_re = re.compile('^[0-9]+[0-9,]+$')
for row in csv.reader(open('input_file.csv')):
  for el_num in len(row):
    if num_re.match(row[el_num]):
      row[el_num] = row[el_num].replace(',', '')
```

...although it would probably be faster not to use the regular expression at all:

```
for row in ([item.replace(',', '') for item in row]
            for row in csv.reader(open('input_file.csv'))):
  do_something_with_your(row)
```

Comment: @RobI yes, it does -- the CSV module strips quotation marks, so it would yield only `12,345` rather than `"12,345"`.

Comment: I like this answer best (can't remove my -1 though).  But I think the last line in there needs to be: `row[el_num] = int(row[el_num].replace(',','')`.  Though you could just get rid of the if statement altogether; I say that adds clarity with just a tiny performance hit (if any).

Comment: @RobI Ooh, good catch -- patched the last line per suggestion. By the way, I'm pretty much certain that -1 votes are in fact retractable.

Comment: @RobI Not a problem -- I'll clean up my own comments to the extent necessary to make the history work.

Comment: While @jdotjdot89 answered my question, I think this answer has just given my a much better approach! I am only still learning Python, so I'm pretty sure most of what I am writing is laughably unPythonic! Live and learn though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Python has a regular expressions module, "re":

http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

However, in this case, you might want to consider using the "partition" function:

```
>>> s = 'some_long_string,"12,345",more_string,"56,6789",and_some_more'
>>> left_part,quote_mark,right_part = s.partition(")
>>> right_part
'12,345",more_string,"56,6789",and_some_more'
>>> number,quote_mark,remainder = right_part.partition(")
'12,345'
```

string.partition("character") splits a string into 3 parts, stuff to the left of the first occurrence of "character", "character" itself and stuff to the right.

Comment: Not quite what I was hoping for, definitely an interesting solution, but I was hoping to match a regular expression to a string component, and replace elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple regex for removing commas from numbers of any length:

```
re.sub(r'(\d+),?([\d+]?)',r'\1\2',mystring)
```